# Haskell: how to extract a value from a Right

Tags: haskell

I am building up a simple script to parse a two-items-per-row CSV file:

```
//Main.hs

module Main where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Csv

type Row = (BL.ByteString, BL.ByteString)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  csvData <- BL.readFile "csvs/twostringsperrow.csv"
  let v = decode NoHeader csvData :: Either String (V.Vector Row)
  putStrLn "All done"
```

The script works. Obviously it doesn't do much at the moment, but it works, which is reassuring.

I want to now interact with this in the GHCi and so I run those couple of lines:

```
$ stack ghci
...
*Main> csvData <- BL.readFile "csvs/twostringsperrow.csv"
*Main> let v = decode NoHeader csvData :: Either String (V.Vector Row)
*Main> v
Right [("1","2"),("3","4")]
```

At this point I can see that the parsing has been successful and would like to get the `[("1","2"),("3","4")]` out of the `Right` into a variable called `df` so that I can have a play with it. i.e.:

```
*Main> let df = <something here> v
*Main> df
[("1","2"),("3","4")]
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *pattern matching* logic here. For example:

```
let Right df = v
```

We thus here unwrap the data out of `Right` data constructor.

You can for example write a function that handles both the `Left` and `Right` case, since it is typically better to implement *total* functions (functions that can process the entire space of values specified by the type).

Comment: While this is fine when the parsing works, if the parser gives a Left value (e.g. for a syntax error in the file) then you will get an unhelpful exception message. The usual approach in an actual program is therefore to say "case v of {Left err -> .... ; Right df -> ....}

Comment: @PaulJohnson: that is exactly the idea of the comment in the last paragraph. Typically one can here use the monad instance of the `Either`, and thus process it as a chain like `someEither >>= (\theright -> ...)`

Answer (score 3):

A basic approach it to use a `case`.

```
do ...
   x <- parse ...
   case x of
      Left e  -> putStrLn ("Parse error" ++ show e)
      Right y -> putStrLn ("Parse OK!" ++ show y)
```

Don't forget that we can not, in general, "remove a `Right`" in a safe way, since a value of type `Either ParseError T` is not necessarily a `Right`, but could also be a `Left`.

Indeed, the parsing library returns such a sum type in order to force us to handle the error, and consider *both* cases.

There are some dangerous partial functions that indeed "remove `Right`" but it is better to avoid them.